# Every other time I reboot, I loose my applications lens in Unity!

Tags: 11.10, unity

Since upgrading to 11.10, I have had issues with Unity.  It seems as though every other time I reboot, the applications lens disappears.  Sometimes it's there, other times it is not.

When it is not there, I obviously can't browse or launch applications.

I have tried re-installing unity, unity-lens-applications, and unity-place-applications using `apt-get install --reinstall`, but no luck.

This is super frustrating.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

[image]

[image: after reboot]

Comment: possibly very similar question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/91731/application-lens-installend-but-missing-in-dash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but with Version: `5.0.0~+bzr1825ubuntu0+611`
I removed `~/.cache/software-center` and it started working again.

Don't know if it is the right thing todo, but it seems to work at least.

Comment: This may have worked for me too.  The application lens has been loading consistently for the past few reboots.  Thank you.