# Applications aren't displayed in dash after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: unity, 12.04, upgrade, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

I have ubuntu box that has been upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04. After the upgrade one of the users cannot see applications in the dash:

[image: screenshot]

Typing a search query doesn't help:
[image: screenshot]

This system was previously upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04 and from 11.04 to 11.10 but no problem happened those times.
I can provide more information like logs, if someone tells me where I can get it.

Comment: Related? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/93893/every-other-time-i-reboot-i-loose-my-applications-lens-in-unity

Comment: No, it's not. I don't loose Applications lens but the lens doesn't display applications. However I will try to apply solutions from that topic to check, if they will help.

Comment: Yes, if you could do that that'd be great.

Comment: Done. Unfortunately that didn't help. Even after restarting the session applications aren't still displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem, moved zeitgeist directory to zeitgeist.bak and re-login:

```
mv ~/.local/share/zeitgeist  ~/.local/share/zeitgeist.bak
```

The problem is that the zeitgeist directory has the wrong permissions. You can also select the folder in Nautilus, and select properties, and make the directory read/writeable for yourself. Then you don't need to log out and in again.

Answer (score 0):

Are the file/directory permissions ok, especially of the ~/.config folder? I've encountered issues myself when updating a ubuntu box and using same username as in the old system. After the update, all files and directories of my user folder had `1001` as owner and group.

Comment: Permissions seem to be the same as the permissions of the other user's .config folder. I performed chown -R myuser:myuser on my home directory. But the problem is still present. Maybe restarting the session can help. Will try to do that.

Comment: No, it didn't. I have logged out and logged back in but I still cannot see applications.